# Why readonly keyword doesn't work with destructuring

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I try create react component with immutable props using react 16.8 and typescipt 3.4.5

In this case typescript throw an error,

```
interface IProps {
  readonly user: {name: string}
}

const User = (props: IProps) => {
  props.user = {name: "Foo"}
  return <>props.user.name</>;
};
```

```
Error:(8, 9) TS2540: Cannot assign to 'user' because it is a read-only property.
```

but when I using destructuring for props typescript allow to modify props:

```
interface IProps {
  readonly user: {name: string}
}

const User = ({user}: IProps) => {
  user = {name: "Foo"}
  return <>user.name</>;
};
```

I expect typescript throw an error in both cases.

Comment: I think in the second case you are deriving a variable off of props and call it user. This you can edit, but it will never change the actual props object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readonly` property can be initialized:

- at the site where it is declared (mirrors `const` in ES6)
- in the constructor of a class

In this code

```
const User = (props: IProps) => {
  props.user = {name: "Foo"}
  return <>props.user.name</>;
};
```

the `props` object and its `props.user` property (which is being passed to `User` component) would have been declared and initialized by the caller of `User` and only at this location can `props.user` be set.

In this code

```
const User = ({user}: IProps) => {
  user = {name: "Foo"}
  return <>user.name</>;
};
```

the property `user` (that is not inside braces) has nothing to do with the interface because `User` itself doesn't implement it. A function that accepts an argument which implements an interface doesn't itself implement this interface.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

I'm not sure about typescript, but in ES6 when you protect a variable with const like this:

`const x = {name: "John"}`

This code will give an error:

`x = {name: "Mikkel"}`

But this will not:

`x.name = "mikkel"`

All it protects against is `x` being overwritten, but not the internals of the object. I suspect typescript is doing the same